# Is there a nice clean way to unset from an array but return that unset value?

Tags: php

Something like the would be nice:

```
$name = unset($array['username']);
```

Leaving $array without a username but assigned to $name.

I'm just looking for the least complex way of doing this really.

Comment: Just feel free to write a function to do it.

Comment: @xdazz Was thinking the same...

Answer (score 2):

`unset` has `void` as return type.

```
void unset ( mixed $var [, mixed $... ] )
```

You can do it like this:

```
$name = $array['username'];
unset($array['username']);
```